# scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: package scala does not have a member Int

Tags: scala, playframework, interpreter

I am currently working on a project using Scala and Play Framework 2. I want to compile some Scala code during runtime and get the result from the interpreter. I found some examples on the internet and finally came up with the following code:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

class Interpreter extends Controller {

    val interpreter = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
    val settings = interpreter.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain].settings
    settings.embeddedDefaults[Interpreter]
    settings.usejavacp.value = true

    def index = Action {
        Ok(views.html.interpreter())
    }

    def interpret(input: String) = Action { 
        implicit request => interpreter.eval("1 to 10 foreach println")
        Ok("Got: " + input)
    }
}

object Interpreter
```

My problem is that I always get an error from `scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: "package scala does not have a member Int"`, when trying to run this code. After some research I found similar problems described in this posts:

[Scala and Play 2.0 Plugins Update 0.38.437 is Out](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2014/06/10/scala-and-play-2-0-plugins-update-0-38-437-is-out/)

[Scala compiler error: package api does not have a member materializeWeakTypeTag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21610848/scala-compiler-error-package-api-does-not-have-a-member-materializeweaktypetag)

My current Scala version is *2.11.4*, so I tried to switch to a different "scala-compiler" and "scala-library" versions in my "build.sbt" file, but with no success. Like it was mentioned in the posts above it is probably a bug in Scala. I wondered if somebody has a solution or perhaps any workaround for the described problem.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get exactly what you want to do but interpret method on your controller should return an Action which is basically a (play.api.mvc.Request => play.api.mvc.Result) function. In your code you have a implicit request => Object (coming from the eval function) and then return the Ok Result. Is this correct?

Comment: My idea was: 
1) to get the input: String from a textfield on the frontend side
2) pass it through to the interpret() function
3) evaluate the input 
4) and finally return the output given from compiler.

Comment: Seems like this issue only Play applications specific. Same topic on Google Groups "scala script engine"  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-script-engine/9YteLsdXPKU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in classpath in projects using Scala and Play Framework 2. 
It can be resolved by populating classpath from SBT to the application:

Add to build.sbt file:

```
val sbtcp = taskKey[Unit]("sbt-classpath")

sbtcp := {
  val files: Seq[File] = (fullClasspath in Compile).value.files
  val sbtClasspath : String = files.map(x => x.getAbsolutePath).mkString(":")
  println("Set SBT classpath to 'sbt-classpath' environment variable")
  System.setProperty("sbt-classpath", sbtClasspath)
}

compile  <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(sbtcp)
```

Code:

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc.{Action, Controller}
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager

class Interpreter extends Controller {

    val interpreter = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
    val settings = interpreter.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain].settings
    //settings.embeddedDefaults[Interpreter] // not need
    //settings.usejavacp.value = true // not need
    val sbtClasspath = System.getProperty("sbt-classpath")
    settings.classpath.value = s".:${sbtClasspath}" // <-- this line fix the problem

    def index = Action {
        Ok(views.html.interpreter())
    }

    def interpret(input: String) = Action { 
        implicit request => interpreter.eval("1 to 10 foreach println")
        Ok("Got: " + input)
    }
}

object Interpreter
```

In production should be used another scenario to get a correct classpath.

Probably using a '-cp' or '-classpath' key from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem by specifying `scala-maven-plugin`

I was using `Scala 2.11.x` and if you dont specify any version in `scala-maven-plugin` by default it goes with latest version which `4.4.0`

Then i changed my `scala-maven-plugin` to 3.2.2 and it works fine.