# "package scala does not have a member Int" in scala 2.11.x

Tags: scala

I want to a compile scala classes in runtime using scala **v2.11.6**.

What can be the reason of the error "**package scala does not have a member Int**"?

```
    scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: package scala does not have a member Int
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.scala$reflect$internal$Definitions$DefinitionsClass$$fatalMissingSymbol(Definitions.scala:1183)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.getMember(Definitions.scala:1200)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$ValueClassDefinitions$class.valueClassSymbol(Definitions.scala:77)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$ValueClassDefinitions$class.IntClass(Definitions.scala:114)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.IntClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:153)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.IntClass(Definitions.scala:153)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$ValueClassDefinitions$class.IntTpe(Definitions.scala:127)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.IntTpe$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:153)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.IntTpe(Definitions.scala:153)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.sig2type$1(ClassfileParser.scala:622)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.sig2type$1(ClassfileParser.scala:720)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.scala$tools$nsc$symtab$classfile$ClassfileParser$$sigToType(ClassfileParser.scala:766)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getType(ClassfileParser.scala:283)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseMethod(ClassfileParser.scala:560)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.scala$tools$nsc$symtab$classfile$ClassfileParser$$queueLoad$1(ClassfileParser.scala:477)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$$anonfun$parseClass$1.apply$mcV$sp(ClassfileParser.scala:487)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:492)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:133)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply$mcV$sp(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader$$anonfun$doComplete$2.apply(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.enteringPhase(SymbolTable.scala:235)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:348)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:212)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1488)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.initialize(Symbols.scala:1633)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1391)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1216)
```

Code snippet:

```
val sem = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
val settings = sem.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain].settings
settings.embeddedDefaults[Int]
settings.usejavacp.value = true

sem.eval("println()") <- error here
```

Seems like this error only Play framework applications specific.

[Test project example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1mzftkoqq31xzo9/sse-test.zip)

Comment: How do you compile? How do the sources look like that you try to compile? We don't have crystal balls.

Comment: Here you are: val sem = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala")
    val settings = sem.asInstanceOf[scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain].settings
    settings.usejavacp.value = true
    sem.eval("println()")

Comment: Issue has been resolved. More details  [here][1]. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470669/scala-reflect-internal-fatalerror-package-scala-does-not-have-a-member-int/29582915#29582915