# Dynamic compilation with scala 2.12 - from sbt test

Tags: scala, dynamic, compilation, sbt, scala-compiler

I want to test a tool I write which transforms some scala source code, I want to check that the transformed code compiles from a sbt test (using scalatest).

I'd like to call programmatically the scala compiler on a String with my source (all is in a standalone file).

I made some progress since the initial question. This code works in my IDE (IntelliJ) but not from a `sbt test` session

```
import java.io.File
import scala.reflect.internal.util.BatchSourceFile
import scala.tools.nsc.{GenericRunnerSettings, Global}

object Compilation {
  val settings = new GenericRunnerSettings(System.out.println _)
//  val sbtClasspath = System.getProperty("sbt-classpath")
//  val s = File.pathSeparator
//  val classPath = s".${s}$sbtClasspath"
//  settings.classpath.append(classPath)
  settings.usejavacp.value = true
  val global = new Global(settings)

  def compiles(code: String): Boolean = {
    val r = new global.Run
    r.compileSources(List(new BatchSourceFile("<partest>", code)))
    val errors = global.reporter.hasErrors
    if (errors) r.reporting.summarizeErrors()
    !errors
  }
}
```

Here is my `build.sbt`

```
name := "CodinGame-Scala-Kit"
version := "0.1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.12.2" % "test"

enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)

//val sbtcp = taskKey[Unit]("sbt-classpath")
//
//sbtcp := {
//  val files: Seq[File] = (fullClasspath in Compile).value.files
//  val sbtClasspath: String = files.map(x => x.getAbsolutePath).mkString(java.io.File.pathSeparator)
//  println("Set SBT classpath to 'sbt-classpath' environment variable")
//  println(sbtClasspath)
//  System.setProperty("sbt-classpath", sbtClasspath)
//}
//
//compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(sbtcp)
```

The initial error is

```
scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError: object scala.annotation.Annotation in compiler mirror not found.
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.signal(MissingRequirementError.scala:17)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.MissingRequirementError$.notFound(MissingRequirementError.scala:18)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.$anonfun$getModuleOrClass$4(Mirrors.scala:54)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:54)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:45)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getModuleOrClass(Mirrors.scala:66)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getClassByName(Mirrors.scala:101)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.getRequiredClass(Mirrors.scala:104)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Mirrors$RootsBase.requiredClass(Mirrors.scala:107)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.AnnotationClass$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1141)
```

I have added the lines commented in `build.sbt` and in the `Compilation` object following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470669/scala-reflect-internal-fatalerror-package-scala-does-not-have-a-member-int/29582915#29582915). It changes nothing in the IDE.

I now have this error on sbt test (compile correctly prints the classpath) :

```
 scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: class StringContext does not have a member f
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.fatalMissingSymbol(Definitions.scala:1236)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.$anonfun$getMember$1(Definitions.scala:1259)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.getMember(Definitions.scala:1254)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.getMemberMethod(Definitions.scala:1288)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass$RunDefinitions.StringContext_f$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1477)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass$RunDefinitions.StringContext_f(Definitions.scala:1477)
[info]   at scala.tools.reflect.FastTrack.$anonfun$fastTrackCache$1(FastTrack.scala:53)
[info]   at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable$perRunCaches$$anon$1.apply(SymbolTable.scala:395)
[info]   at scala.tools.reflect.FastTrack.contains(FastTrack.scala:20)
[info]   at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.methodSig(Namers.scala:1388)
```

Comment: I'm now using latest sbt (0.13.15) which makes the last error simpler. Could be linked to this similar bug ... https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10058

Comment: I am seeing the opposite problem. It works from sbt but fails in IntelliJ.

Comment: Reloading the project seemed to fix it. Not sure what the issue was.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach looks similar to things which have worked for me, You are obviously missing a dependency somewhere. An empty Settings won't work. 
Either change settings bootclasspath

or simply use
settings.usejavacp.value = true

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a reliable way to compile any String :

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

object Compiler {

  def compile[A](string: String): A = {
    val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
    val tree    = toolbox.parse(string)
    toolbox.eval(tree).asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}
```

with

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % "2.12.10"
```